# Is it possible to access the currently opened browser tab from an android application?

Tags: android

If I create an application, which the user installs on his Android device, is it possible for that application, that from the background, it can access the currently opened browser tab, and if the user navigates to a specific domain with his browser, the app sends a push notification, or maybe notifies the user about a promotion on that domain?

Answer (score 2):

well, for usual apps this isn't possible for security reasons obviusly. but it probably may be done using [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service). note that Google is filtering apps which have such big privileges and won't let your app to Play Store if it will be using `AccessibilityService` to such "trivial" operation (isn't very helpful, for sure isn't accessibility-kind-of)